# Is https work properly?

Tags: ssl, https, openshift

My site on openshift works with `http` and  `https` prefix. Does it mean that `https` is allready set up properly so I do not need any additional steps to configure it there? Do I need any ssl sertificate for https?

Comment: which version of openshift are you using v2 or v3? v3 is in developer preview

Comment: @SouravGhosh v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments, you are using openshift v2.

Here you can use either custom rhcloud.com subdomain or use your own domain name.

All applications URL under rhcloud.com (say, example-username.rhcloud.com) use a shared SSL certificate. So, If you use rhcloud.com subdomain, you don't need to configure anything. They automatically provide  *.rhcloud.com wildcard certificate.

To use HTTPS for your custom domain name (say, www.example.com) or alias, you need to upload your own certificate. To upload custom SSL certificate, You need to subscribe to a Premium plan. Free plan does not allow custom SSL certificate.

You can read more about how to set up custom domain, alias or SSL certificate, [here](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/domains-ssl.html). The previous documentation link is valid only for openshift v2.